# How do you make Unity structs such as Vector3 immutable?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to borrow the idea from functional programming that all variables should be immutable unless it is explicitly used as mutable state (although state should be minimal, even the strictest functional programmers still have to use a database, which is literally just mutable state).

I'm not sure how to do this in C# with structs like the Vector3 struct.

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: What about a struct with a constructor with parameters to set the initial value of a readonly properties (only getters)

Answer (score 1):

You can't change behavior of an existing type like `Vector3`.

Your only option for existing types is to not use methods that mutate state. In case of [Vector3](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html) is not very restrictive as most of the methods return new vector. You can either just enforce that through code reviews or find/write tools that would flag usage of specific methods at edit/compile time.

Note that inability to modify values in place (like update just x position of all points in an array) comes at performance cost - for performance sensitive environments like gaming code the benefits *you* are getting of immutable types  may not outweigh performance degradation or cost of achieving the same performance.

Comment: Good point, at least the methods on Vector3 don't mutate, which is more than we can say for half of the javascript language